SpatiaLite database in Delphi Berlin
Has anyone succeeded using spatiaLite in Delphi (Berlin)?
I have tried to use FireDAC but also to load the sqlite3.dll in code and then load the mod_spatialite.dll, but the module cannot be used. I cannot read geometry or MakePoint, so I assume it is not correctly loaded.
Everything is 64 bit.
